# Oracle SQL : Extract all matched string in each row

Tags: regex, oracle, oracle12c

Suppose that I have this table `MESSAGE` with two columns `ITEM` and `CONTENT`

```
ITEM1 | Dear ${username}, you have changed your address to ${address}
ITEM2 | Hi ${username}, thank you for attending this event.
```

Currently, I want to display each word with this pattern ${variable}. The expected end result is

```
ITEM1 | ${username}, ${address}
ITEM2 | ${username}
```

Whats the correct Oracle SQL query to achieve this ? I have tried something like this but it just list out the content with matching regex.

```
SELECT ITEM, REGEXP_SUBSTR(CONTENT, '^.*\$\{.*\}.*$', 1, 1) FROM MESSAGE;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use `(\$\{.+?\})` - using `?` makes it a non-greedy match of one or more characters between `{}`
`()` captures the group.

A `connect by` loop (with `PRIOR` and `SYS_GUID()`) with `level` is used to extract all possible matches in a line.

`LISTAGG` does the concatenation.

```
WITH message AS (
    SELECT
        'ITEM1' AS item,
        'Dear ${username}, you have changed your address to ${address}' AS content
    FROM
        dual
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        'ITEM2',
        'Hi ${username}, thank you for attending this event.'
    FROM
        dual
) 
SELECT item,LISTAGG(content,',') WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY lvl )
FROM
(
SELECT
    item,
    regexp_substr(content,'(\$\{.+?\})',1,level,NULL,1) as content,
    level as lvl
  FROM
      message
CONNECT BY level <= regexp_count(content,'\$\{.+?\}')
           AND PRIOR item = item
           AND PRIOR sys_guid() IS NOT NULL
           ) GROUP BY item;
```

[**Demo**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=d8d9e553d5f25a6a6ed9046b5b695ea0)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not that good at regular expressions, see if this can help:

```
SQL> with message (item, content) as
  2    (select 'ITEM1', 'Dear ${username}, you have changed your address to ${address}' from dual union
  3     select 'ITEM2', 'Hi ${username}, thank you for attending this event.' from dual
  4    )
  5  select item,
  6    regexp_substr(content, '\$\{\w+}', 1, 1) the_first,
  7    regexp_substr(content, '\$\{\w+}', 1, 2) the_second
  8  from message;

ITEM  THE_FIRST            THE_SECOND
----- -------------------- --------------------
ITEM1 ${username}          ${address}
ITEM2 ${username}

SQL>
```

What does it do?

- `\$` is here to escape the dollar sign, because it is used as an *anchor* for the end of the string (so - escape it)
- the same goes for `\{` as curly brackets represent number of appearances (so - escape it)
- `\w+` takes the whole word
- `1, 1` and `1, 2`: starting from the first character, take the first (1, **1**) or the second (1, **2**) appearance of that expression

It is trivial to concatenate these two and separate them with a comma.

Comment: This assumes there are at most two variables per CONTENT. It is not clear from the OP's question if that assumption is valid.

Answer (score 0):

```
with
  inputs ( str ) as (
    select 'Dear ${username}, you have changed your address to ${address}' 
    from   dual
  )
select rtrim(regexp_replace(str, '.*?(\${[^}]*}|$)', '\1, '), ', ') as vars 
from   inputs;

VARS                   
-----------------------
${username}, ${address}
```